# Eslint asking to destructure array.split()?

Tags: javascript, eslint, destructuring

Eslint is asking me to use array destructuring on the following statement:

```
sessID = sessID.split('.')[0].split(':')[1];
```

How could you possibly destructure something like this? All I'm doing is extracting a substring out of a bigger string using `split()`. It's the `split()` function that's turning the string into an array, right?

Comment: Destructuring doesn't have anything to do with extracting parts of strings. It's about *data structures*, arrays and objects.

Comment: And I have no idea what's triggering Eslint to offer that advice; probably it sees the array indexing, but you'd still need two statements.

Comment: eslint ignore line :)

Comment: I just checked and it doesnot show me any error. Can you show your `.eslintrc` maybe you wrote something.

Comment: Does it want `const [junk, correctSessID] = sessID.split(".")[0].split(':')`, probably will complain about unused variables. lol

Comment: This worked. Thanks.
`
const [a] = sessID.split('.');
const [,q] = a.split(':');
`

Comment: @epascarello you can omit `junk`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linters provide tips for the general case. You can safely ignore these tips if appropriate, as in this case. This won't be easier to read with array destructuring. Proof:

```
 ([, sessID] = sessID.split('.')[0].split(':'));
```

Comment: Why the extra parentheses around the assignment? Seems unnecessary